# Format code with VIM using external commands

Tags: vim

I know that using VIM I can format C++ code just using

```
gg=G
```

Now I have to format 30 files, so doing it by hand becomes tedious. I had a look how to do it passing external commands to VIM, so I tried

```
vim -c gg=G -c wq file.cpp
```

but it does not work.

Can you give me a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not load all the files up in buffers and use `bufdo` to execute the command on all of them at one time?

```
:bufdo "execute normal gg=G"
```

Comment: how can you load up all the files in buffers? using a "for" loop in bash script? thanks

Comment: No need for a script if your shell supports file globbing. For example, if I wanted to load up all the ruby files in the directory `~/mycode`, I'd type `$ vim ~/mycode/*.rb`

Comment: great! I achieved to edit them all. Now how can I save them? I tried :bufdo "execute normal wq" but it does not work

Comment: last thing, I checked that doing :bufdo "execute normal gg=G" over an individual file does not work

Comment: all you need is `:wqa`. It means write quit all.

Answer (score 5):

Change `-c gg=G` to `-c 'normal! gg=G'`. `-c` switch accepts only ex mode commands, `gg=G` are two normal mode commands.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a slight change on the `:bufdo` answer.  I prefer the arg list instead of the buffer list, so I don't need to worry about closing current buffers or opening up new vim session.  For example:

```
:args ~/src/myproject/**/*.cpp | argdo execute "normal gg=G" | update
```

- `args` sets the arglist, using wildcards (`**` will match the current directory as well as subdirectories)
- `|` lets us run multiple commands on one line
- `argdo` runs the following commands on each arg (it will swallow up the second `|`)
- `execute` prevents `normal` from swallowing up the next pipe.
- `normal` runs the following normal mode commands (what you were working with in the first place)
- `update` is like `:w`, but only saves when the buffer is modified.

This `:args ... | argdo ... | update` pattern is very useful for any sort of project wide file manipulation (e.g. search and replace via '%s/foo/bar/ge' or setting uniform `fileformat` or `fileencoding`).